# How to write hours of operations for Schema.org 'Preschool'?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'm doing structured markup for multiple preschools. While the `ChildCare` type allows for `openingHours`, the `Preschool` type does not. Can anyone recommend a good way to include this? I'm keen on keeping it the `Preschool` type if only because that's what the category is set as in GMB.

Here is what I have so far for the entire structured markup. I'm also trying to find a way to get `priceRange` in there but can't seem to figure it out.

```json
{                                                                       
    "@context": "http://schema.org",                                                                    
    "@type": "Preschool",                                                                   
    "name": "Name of Preschool",                                                                    
    "description": "Description of Preschool",                                                                  
    "address": {                                                                    
        "@type": "PostalAddress",                                                               
        "streetAddress": "Address of Preschool",                                                                
        "addressLocality": "City Name",
        "addressRegion": "State Name",                                                          
        "postalCode": "Zip Code",                                                               
        "addressCountry": "United States"
        },
    "image": "Image URL",                                                                   
    "logo": "Image URL",                                                                    
    "url": "Preschool URL",
    "foundingDate": "2016-05-01",

    "founder": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Name of Founder"
    },

    "numberOfEmployees": {
        "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
        "value": "2"
    },

    "contactPoint": {
        "@type": "ContactPoint",
        "telephone": "Phone Number",
        "contactType": "Customer Service",
        "areaServed": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Neighborhood of the Preschool",
            "branchCode": "Preschool Code", 
            "hasMap": "Google Map URL",
            "geo": {
                "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
                "latitude": "Coordinate",
                "longitude": "Coordinate"     
        } 
        }    
    },
    "parentOrganization": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Name of Parent Company",
        "url": "URL of Parent Company"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for the [`ChildCare`](https://schema.org/ChildCare) type, because it has [`LocalBusiness`](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness) as parent type, which comes with the properties `openingHours` and `priceRange`.

If your preschools really are businesses, too, you could use a MTE by applying both types:

```json
"@type": ["Preschool", "LocalBusiness"]
```

This allows you to use properties from `Preschool` as well as from `LocalBusiness`.

Comment: I had no idea you would do that. Does that confuse Google at all? This is literally the first time I've seen that.

Comment: @BradMcHargue: Google only makes use of specific Schema.org terms in specific contexts, e.g., for rich results. Each rich result, and which terms are required/recommended, is documented by Google. For example, for the [local business rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business?hl=en), they don’t document whether or not additional types are fine. But there is no reason to assume that they aren’t, it’s a perfectly normal/intended method for providing structured data.